# Jquery not loading in jsFiddle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, jsfiddle

I am trying to use jQuery-ui's drag and drop with angular js for a list of accordions ...
However my drag and drop doesn work in jsFiddle ( works in local server) as firebug states that : ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined .

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TTrdm/59/) is the jsFiddle

```
               <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

<title>Task WhiteBoard</title>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />     
<meta name="description" content="AngularJS + jQuery UI Drag-n-Drop" />
<title>Angular Drag and Drop</title>
</head>


<body ng-controller="dndCtrl" ng-cloak>
<h3>Task Whiteboard</h3>


<div class='list1' droppable value='1' >    

<div class='header'>
    Free Tasks
</div>

<div class="below-header">

</div>

<div  ng-repeat="item in list1" data-index="{{$index}}" draggable>
    <div class="zippy" zippy-title="{{item.name}}">
            {{item.content.newLabel}}    <br/>
            {{item.content.desc}}    <br/>
            {{item.content.effort}}    <br/>
            {{item.content.owner}}    <br/>
            {{item.content.issues}}    <br/>    
            {{item.content.comments}}    <br/>
            {{item.content.dependency}}    <br/>
    </div>    
</div>    
</div>    

<div class='list2' droppable value='2'>    

<div class='header'>
    Claimed Tasks
</div>

<div class="below-header">

</div>

<div ng-repeat="item in list2" data-index="{{$index}}" draggable>
    <div class="zippy" zippy-title="{{item.name}}">
            {{item.content.newLabel}}    <br/>
            {{item.content.desc}}    <br/>
            {{item.content.effort}}    <br/>
            {{item.content.owner}}    <br/>
            {{item.content.issues}}    <br/>    
            {{item.content.comments}}    <br/>
            {{item.content.dependency}}    <br/>
    </div>    
</div>    
</div>

<div class='list3' droppable value='3'>

<div class='header'>
    Completed Tasks
</div>

<div class="below-header">

</div>

<div ng-repeat="item in list3" data-index="{{$index}}" draggable>
        <div class="zippy" zippy-title="{{item.name}}">
            {{item.content.newLabel}}    <br/>
            {{item.content.desc}}    <br/>
            {{item.content.effort}}    <br/>
            {{item.content.owner}}    <br/>
            {{item.content.issues}}    <br/>    
            {{item.content.comments}}    <br/>
            {{item.content.dependency}}    <br/>
        </div>    
</div>
</div>    


<div style="clear:both;">
    list 1 size : {{list1.length}}    <br/>
    list 2 size : {{list2.length}}    <br/>
    list 3 size : {{list3.length}}    <br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may not have selected the jQuery for it on fiddle, check it over here, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/TTrdm/60/

Comment: @Adil: if you look at the manage resources, I think he has already added jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Take A look on the Left Panel of `JSFiddle`, there you have selected `Pure JS`, if you want to use 
Jquery UI then choose `jquery version 1.7.2` and check the checkBox `jquery UI 1.8.18` which is  below that.

Answer (score 0):

Your managed resources are out of order. You need to reorder them with jquery first, then jquery ui, etc. That will solve the JS error that jQuery is undefined.

Comment: Thanks :) that worked ... but now my drag and drop functionalities arent working as angular js framework isnt active maybe

Comment: [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/VJ94U/) seems to work. I don't see anything that makes a difference between it and yours.

Comment: I didn use services in my script ... that seems to be the only diference :) ...thanks i will look through it :)